# How do I redefine a module in requirejs?

Tags: requirejs

This question has 3 parts. I have two modules `a` and `b`.

1. How do I redefine `b` after it was required initially?
2. If `a` depends on `b`, how do I then update `a` to use the new `b`?
3. How can I find all modules which depend on b and update them?

For example;

```
 define('a',['b'],function(b){return {name:'A',other:b}}); 
 define('b',function(){return {name:'B'}}); 
 require(['a']); 
 require('a');
```

Answer (score 4):

OK , I figured out 1) using `undef`

```
require.undef('b')
define('b',function(){return {name:'B2'}});
```

2) can use `undef` also but it's clunky

```
require.undef('a')
require.undef('b')
define('b',function(){return {name:'B2'}}); 
require(['a'])
require('a')
```

Any answers for part 3?

Comment: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#undef says: 'it will not remove the module from other modules that are already defined and got a handle on that module as a dependency when they executed.' suggests that we use `onResourceLoad` - https://github.com/requirejs/requirejs/wiki/Internal-API:-onResourceLoad